# IntelliSense isn't working when I type console.log();

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I feel like I might of edited the json file of IntelliSense on accident because console.log doesnt come up in IntelliSense. Its been like this for at least a week and a half and its very annoying. IntelliSense works on every bit of code except for console.log();

Ive restatred the program multiple times. I also tried to read the VS Code documentation and I have not found a straightfoward answer.

I just really wish IntelliSense would work when I type console.log. I keep having to escape out of it just to type console.log and enter back into it when I want to type the rest of my code.

Comment: What if you uninstall and reinstall VSCode

Comment: @Samathingamajig I actually just went to the VS code website and downloaded the newest version. (I had the newest version downloaded) and it fixed the problem.